# How to I convert a Silverlight 3.0 project to Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: silverlight-3.0, silverlight-4.0, upgrade

I have a solution with several Silverlight Class Libraries and a Silverlight Application in it.  I was originally built in VS 2008 with Silverlight 3.0.  What changes do I need to make so that it builds using Silverlight 4.0?  I already have VS 2010 and the Silverlight 4.0 toolkit installed.

When I opened the project it seems to have upgraded to .NET 4.0 in my ASP.NET Web Project but not the Silverlight projects.  Pretty sure they are still building against .NET 3.5 and Silverlight 3.0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS2010 supports Silverlight mutlitargeting as well as .NET multitargeting, you have the option in each Silverlight Project Page to upgrade the target type from Silverlight 3 to Silverlight 4.

Comment: Correct.  Took me awhile to find it for some odd reason.  But there it is...  just right click on your Project in the Solution Explorer goto "Properties".  On the Silverlight Tab there is an option for "Target Silverlight Version".  Changed that on all my projects and I'm using SL 4.0.